# Switch website encoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am trying to convert my existing PHP webpage to use UTF-8 encoding.

To do so, I have done the following things:

1. specified UTF-8 as the charset in the meta content tag at the start of my webpage.
2. change the default_charset to UTF-8 in the php.ini.
3. specified UTF-8 as the iconv encoding in the php.ini file.
4. specified UTF-8 in my .htaccess file using: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8.

Yet after all that, when i echo mb_internal_encoding(), it shows as ISO-8859-1.  What am I missing here?  I know I could use auto_prepend to attach a script that changes the default encoding to UTF-8, but I'm just trying to understand what I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that that function is reporting on the PHP file itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mb_internal_encoding()` doesn't effect the output of your scripts per se, it effects the *default* encoding when using the [multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) and the conversion of POST and GET inputs.

Simply set with

```
mbstring.internal_encoding='UTF-8'
```

in your **php.ini** file, or programmatically with:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Speaking of the mb_ functions, you'll need to rewrite your scripts to use these, e.g. `mb_strlen()` instead of `strlen.()`, etc.

Also check what HTTP content-type headers are being outputted, though from what you've done it should be ok.

If you using a database, you'll also have to convert that too, and specify that you're using UTF-8 when connecting to it.

Comment: Thanks. that mbstring.internal_encoding (in the php.ini) worked perfectly and was what i was looking for, compared to setting it on every page using php.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that you can SET that variable using

```
/* Set internal character encoding to UTF-8 */
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

which should get rid of your problem :)

Comment: yes I understand that I could set the encoding using that function, but it seems redundant to set the internal encoding on every page, when i'm sure there's a global place to specify the encoding.